# obtain data using a button from within a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

After exhausting the internet I have not found many solution so I ask on here. so I have a repeater displaying product information from a database in which I bounded to the repeater they show the following productName, productDescription, quantity and price.

what i want to find out is how to use a button named 'add to cart' to select the row of data the button is clicked from.

here is what I tried to do but i can only bring forward a single piece of information i.e. productName I want to bring across the Product quantity and price as well.

here is the web page button I am using

`<asp:Button ID="Cartbutt" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" CommandName="select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductName")%>' />`

the behind code code:

`protected void A4Repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "select")
        {
            String ProductName = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
        }
    }`

i appreciate any help you provide thanks in advance as i am pretty new to asp.net and c#.

Comment: You description is not too clear - Is product quatity a TextBox so the user enters the quantity?

Comment: there is pre labelled quantitites in my database in which im retreiving

Comment: Then @Arron Palmer's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an id as your CommandArgument.  When you pick it up from the code behind, get the item fresh from your data store.  Your UI should not be driving business decisions as data can be too easily hacked before posting.

Update based on comments.  Use the ProductId in the CommandArgument:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId")%>'
```

The code-behind:

```
if (e.CommandName == "select")
{
    int productId = (int)e.CommandArgument;
    // insert logic to get the product from the data source and use it
}
```

Thanks to LiquaFoo for the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Examle from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you for your examples , now to get the product from the data-source do I create a new connection ? how do i than send and bind that data on another page i have been trying to find a way to do this but dont understand how, the other page will be a shopping cart page